# How to implement cleanall in when a common make file is used

Tags: c++, makefile

Hi I am using common makefile.inc for my project.  For my src folders, I define a makefile which sets some variables and includes makefile.inc.  I can also define DIRS= variable (sample #2) which will call make -C on each one of the directories specified there.   This all works.  However, I cannot get a "clean" or "cleanall" to work properly.  If DIRS= is defined, I need a way to go through all the directories listed and call "make -C xxx clean".   Any ideas?

### Sample makefile #1

```
TYPE = exe
SOURCES = test.cpp
INCLUDES = -I. -I/usr/local/include -I../src
LIBS = -lpcre
OUT = test

include ../../makefile.inc
```

### Sample makefile #2

```
DIRS = src test

include ../makefile.inc
```

### makefile.inc

```
OBJS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

ifeq ($(CFG),)
CFG=debug
endif

ifeq ($(CFG),debug)
CXXFLAGS += -g -Wall -DNDEBUG
else
CXXFLAGS += -O2 -Wall
endif

all: dirs cfgcheck $(OUT)

.PHONY: clean cleanall all

cfgcheck:
ifneq ($(CFG),release)
ifneq ($(CFG),debug)
    @echo "Error: Invalid CFG '$(CFG)'' (options: debug,release)"
    @exit 1
endif
endif
    @echo "Making '$(CURDIR)' CFG="$(CFG)

$(OUT): $(OBJS)
ifeq ($(TYPE),lib)
    $(AR) rcs $(OUT) $(OBJS)
endif
ifeq ($(TYPE),exe)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ ${LDFLAGS} $(LIBS)
endif

-include $(OBJS:.o=.d)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(INCLUDES) $(CXXFLAGS) $*.cpp -o $*.o
    $(CXX) -MM $(CXXFLAGS) $*.cpp > $*.d
    @cp -f $*.d $*.d.tmp
    @sed -e 's/.*://' -e 's/\\$$//' < $*.d.tmp | fmt -1 | sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/$$/:/' >> $*.d
    @rm -f $*.d.tmp

dirs: $(DIRS)
$(DIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OUT) *.o *.d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
DIRS = src test

clean: TARG:=clean
clean: $(DIRS)

.PHONY: $(DIRS)

$(DIRS):
        @$(MAKE) -C $@ $(TARG)
```

If you don't like using the names of directories as phony targets, there are alternatives that are slightly more complicated...

Comment: This almost works.  I added the above but as "cleanall" since I need the original clean there to do the file removal.  The only problem is that now I get the following warnings (with any invokation of make)../makefile.inc:62: warning: overriding commands for target `src'
../makefile.inc:50: warning: ignoring old commands for target `src'
../makefile.inc:62: warning: overriding commands for target `test'
../makefile.inc:50: warning: ignoring old commands for target `test'

Comment: My mistake--I had duplicates $(DIRS) phony target.  Thanks Beta!